# Inserting data into multiple tables with foreign key using CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried to insert data into multiple tables that have foreign key, using CodeIgniter. 
here's my first table called **koor_pen**

no_koor (*primary*) | utm_y | utm_x | latit | longi

here's my second table called **input_pen**

no_form (*primary*) | kode_bps | no_obs | no_koor (*foreign*) | t_tanah | catatan

here's my controller

```
function c_submit(){
    $data = array(
        'no_form' => $this->input->post('noform'),
        'kode_bps' => $this->input->post('kodebps'),
        'no_obs' => $this->input->post('noobs'),
        'no_koor' => $this->input->post('nokoor'),
        'tanaman_u' => $this->input->post('tutama'),
        't_tanah' => $this->input->post('ttanah'),
        'catatan' => $this->input->post('cat')
    );

    $datakoor = array(
        'no_koor' => $this->input->post('nokoor'),
        'utm_y' => $this->input->post('y'),
        'utm_x' => $this->input->post('x'),
        'latit' => $this->input->post('deg')." ".
                    $this->input->post('min')." ".
                    $this->input->post('sec'),
        'longi' => $this->input->post('deg2')." ".
                    $this->input->post('min2')." ".
                    $this->input->post('sec2')
    );

    $no_obs = $this->session->userdata('no_obs');
    $this->m_input->m_submit($data, $datakoor);
    redirect(base_url("c_input"));
}
```

and the model

```
function m_submit($data, $datakoor) {

    $this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->insert('koor_pen', $datakoor); 
    $no_koor = $this->db->insert_id(); 

    $this->db->where('no_koor',$no_koor);
    $this->db->insert('input_pen', $data);

    $this->db->trans_complete(); 

    return $this->db->insert_id(); 

}
```

when I run the code, it shows an error like this
[image]

Comment: Please check value you are adding in child table that exist in your master table.

Comment: What if the two tables is inputted in the same time in one form? @PankajSharma

Comment: @Kiki will you check my answer below?

Comment: @Kiki plz first check in koor_pen table record is inserted or not.

Comment: it really work, thanks for your help @B.Desai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value is getting null. You have to pass `$no_koor` in `$data` so that value can be replaced. Try this:

```
function m_submit($data, $datakoor) {

    $this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->insert('koor_pen', $datakoor); 
    $no_koor = $this->db->insert_id(); 

    //$this->db->where('no_koor',$no_koor);
    $data['no_koor'] = $no_koor;
    $this->db->insert('input_pen', $data);

    $this->db->trans_complete(); 

    return $this->db->insert_id(); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here 
no_koor (foreign) this is you foreign key and in your query no_koor this field is getting "" in your query as you send in image. so please check your query first.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to `foreign key constraint` as shown in your image. The rule is, you can only add or update a value in `child` table which are already present in `parent` table. So at the time of insertion make sure the value you are trying to insert in `child` table, already exist in `parent` table.

Sometimes the insertion sequence also matters, may be the value is their in the query, but you are running child table query first. So check the order also in that case.

Comment: What if the two tables is inputted in the same time in one form?

Comment: The sequence is like Add data in master first and then in child

Comment: so it is possible or not when i inputted two table in the same time in one form?

Comment: Yes, just follow the above sequence

Comment: yes i did, but it doesn't work at all. can you help me by seeing my model?